# Why isn't my Merge working?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, datatable, dataset

I have what I am sure is a typical situation.

I have a DB and I have an XML document of data. I'd like to combine the 2 and update the db.

I have 'fill'ed a DataSet and/or DataTable with the DB data, and if I modify the data in that structure i can call Update and all is well.

Here is what I have.

```
con.Open();
adapter.Fill(ds2, "BASIC");
ds.ReadXmlSchema(@"C:\asis.xsd");
ds.ReadXml("c:\\asis.xml");

// This is the XML data
DataTable loadeddt = ds.Tables["BASIC"];

// This is from the DB
DataTable dbdt = ds2.Tables["BASIC"];

// I want to put the data from xml into the dataset from the DB
dbdt.Merge(loadeddt);


// I want to them put those changes in the db
adapter.Fill(dbdt);
```

Here is what happens, before I loaded the XSD I got an exception saying that types didn't match.

Now I get nothing, no exception no changes. neither of the DataTable show changes and neither does the DB.

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

If I change the last line to Update I get the following:

Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_BASIC'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.BASIC'.

I have noticed that if you do a .Rows.Count pre/post the merge the record count goes from 10 to 20 so it is combining them... not merging them. argh!

FUTHER MORE if I call dbdt.GetChanges(); it returns the whole lot. if i accept changes and update it still does nothing.

Comment: I don't get it. How can this be so hard, this must be a typical problem? The xml I am trying to import is a 'WriteXML' version of the dataset that has been tweaked.. so it isn't like it ought to be a formatting issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should call [`Update`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.update.aspx) instead of `Fill` for this line:

```
// I want to them put those changes in the db 
adapter.Fill(dbdt);
```

**After question update:**
You're inserting a key that already exists.  Either the merge is telling the adapter that it should insert when it should update or the DB fill isn't returning all rows.  Hard to tell with what's given.

This seems like somewhat of a hack but if you know what rows should be considered updates, you can call [SetModified](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.setmodified.aspx) on those rows.

Comment: Ah yes I remember now when I did that I got the following: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_BASIC'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.BASIC'.

Comment: I have updated further. Merge appears to be reporting all rows as NEW and not UPDATED. can't fathom why... what more would you need to see to be sure? there really isn't much more..

Comment: @JonH:  I've updated my answer.  I don't have a good solution for you though.

Comment: problem is it appears to concatinating the 2 data tables not merging them so there is nothing to mark as modified.

Answer (score 0):

Right guys,

I found this article:

http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-ado-net/14201/Merge-function-in-DataSet

Basically the XSD needs to completely describe the primary key for the merge to work.

Essentially I needed to add:

```
<xs:key name="ROOTKey1"  msdata:PrimaryKey="true">
    <xs:selector xpath=".//BASIC" />
    <xs:field xpath="MEMBNO" />
</xs:key>
```